# Are there any post-high school Israeli yeshiva programs that offer semicha "credits"?

Tags: product-recommendation, eretz-yisrael, yeshiva-school, semicha, college-university-school

Many American yeshiva bochrim spend 1 - 1.5 years (average) learning in Israel after high school before they enter college. I know that most of them offer credits where some of them can be transferred to various secular colleges.

I am unaware, though, of any programs that offer credits towards rabbinical semicha at a kollel such as Ner Yisra'el or something similar (i.e. - a known "accredited" Semicha program.) Are there any? If so, can you name a few or, better, point me to a web list or contact person where I can learn more?

Comment: Ner Israel does not have a Semicha program.  You learn the material and take a test from R' Yosef Berger, and you have to pass Mishna Berura tests - if you happen to know it already, then you can take the tests that much sooner.  Many Yeshivas are like that, with the possible addition of a requirement to be in the Yeshiva for a given amount of time.  YU has a Semicha Program, but I don't think you can transfer anything to it.

Comment: @YEZ - You seem to know the Ner program / structure quite well. Are you a "grad"?

Comment: guilty as charged

Comment: @YEZ - Nothing to feel "guilty" about. They have a superb reputation. Normally, I would ask you for a contact person for more info, but as this is for my deaf son, I will prob. contact Rav Kakon, whom I believe graduated from there, himself.

Comment: There are semicha programs that work on credits? Learn something new every day.

Comment: @YEZ Is the mishna berurah test in addition to all the standard topics or does it substitute for some things like hilchos shabbos?

Comment: @Yitzchak it is everything except cheled daled - they are ok if you don't know hilchos eruvin.  Rav Berger will give you semicha in hilchos shabbos separately if you ask him, but that won't just be mishna berura.

Comment: I think eruvin is a separate bechina everywhere. My shabbos curriculum (R' Zalman Nechemia, never finished) didn't include eruvin either

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because Mi Yodeya is a question and answer site for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more. Not about college credits.

Comment: @DannySchoemann This appears to be a [local service recommendation](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3375/5151), which we decided is on topic.

Comment: @Scimonster - then maybe the FAQ should be updated. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @DannySchoemann I don't see where it says that stuff is off topic.

Comment: @Scimonster - seriously? Anything not on-topic is by default off topic. ("On the other hand, questions unrelated to Judaism... ...are off topic") On-topic is defined as: If you have a question about... @ Jewish law or practice (what to do or why) @ Jewish philosophy @ a Jewish text (explaining a passage)
 @ history of Judaism @ language used in Judaism @ general knowledge (science, etc.) as it relates directly to Judaism

Comment: @DannySchoemann Then i recommend you bring it up on [meta].

Answer (score 2):

Among other requirements, semicha from Rabbi Isaac Elchanan Theological Seminary, an affiliate of Yeshiva University, requires two years of Talmud study.  If a person studied in Israel for two (or more) years, his last year of undergraduate Talmud can also count as one of the years of Talmud for semicha.  So in a sense, he is receiving credit towards semicha.  I am not sure if this applies only if his undergraduate work is done at YU, or even if he obtains a Bachelor of Talmudic Literature from other places.

Comment: I've heard that the BTL is enough at YU